# Can't create Lightning Component Tab?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, tab

Could anyone tell me, why I can't create Lightning Component Tab on my full sandbox on 16 enterprise edition?
I just can't see Lightning Component Tab related list in the Setup | Tabs section... So, After creating component I can't use it neither in Lightning Component Tab and in Lightning App Builder too (in the custom components section).

Thanks,
Ruslan Kurchenko

Comment: give us some more information please! What happens when you try to create the tab? What screens are you going to? Does your component implement apphostable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to setup MyDomain for that.
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_name_define.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

Add implements="force:appHostable" in the  component
Example:

Answer (score 0):

If you havent deployed your My Domain to users then you will not be able to see the Lightning Components related list under Setup > Create > Tabs. Until then you will see only Lightning Pages related list.